# MongoDB findOne method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

### So I am trying to find a document inside a collection from my mongodb cluster. I am using the `mongodb` npm package , and I am having trouble using it.

```
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { getGuild } from "../../../util/guild";
import { dbConnect } from "../../../util/mongodb";
import { NextIronRequest, withSession } from "../../../util/session";

const handler = async(req: NextIronRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const { db } = await dbConnect();
    const collection = await db.collection("prefix").findOne({ "guildId": "878239227207372830" })
    res.send(collection)
  } else {
    res.status(405);
    res.end();
  }
};

export default withSession(handler);
```

### So this is currently the code I am using, the `dbConnect()` function works, but I can seem to find the document. [image: MongoDB Document Image] , this is the current document I input in the collection, and when I used the `findOne` method, it just returns null. If anyone knows the problem, feel free to respond :)

Comment: `null` (or `undefined`) for a returned value from a `findOne` means the query has not found a document. I suggest you try the `findOne` without a filter and see what is returned - `findOne({})`.

Comment: It still returns `null` , I used the `find()` method and no filter , and it returns an empty array

Comment: Empty array means - there is no data (you are probably using the `find({}).toArray()`). Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Yes, when I used `insertOne` and `updateOne` for the `users` collection, it updates the document.

Comment: What about the `prefix` collection? Are you able to perform any other operations? Is it in the same database as the `users`?

Comment: Looks like I mistyped the MongoDB NAME in the connect function and I checked the wrong collection. I am sorry about that